# Query + Importrange with column selection to display matching a non-displayed criteria

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to do the following:

1. Bring information to a Google sheet from another Google sheet using `importrange`.
2. I need the information of two columns, but bases on the criteria of a third column I do not need to display.

This is what I already tried to do:

**Script**

```
=query(importrange("Link1","Sheet!b1:h"),"SELECT G, H where B = "Criteria_to_meet"",-1)
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help. Your comments were very usesful. This is how it finally worked.

Cell `A1` contains `criteria_to_meet`, and we expanded the `importrange` to contain the first column.

#### Formula

```
=QUERY(importrange("Link1","Sheet!A1:H"),CONCATENAR("SELECT Col7, Col8 WHERE Col2='",A1,"'"),1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the query is loading data via importrange, you need to use the other select notation, `Col1,Col2` rather than `A,B`.

Hence, instead of `select G,H where B` you would use `select Col7,Col8 where Col2`.

In addition, `"Criteria_to_meet"` would most likely need to be `""Criteria_to_meet""` (double quotes x 2) or `'Criteria_to_meet'` (single quotes).